# MySQL query to fetch result between start date and end date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two dates say `start_date = 2013-04-12` and `end_date =  2013-04-30`
 and my table contains row with `start_date = 2013-04-12` and `end_date = 2013-04-16`

I want to fetch records whose start date is greater 2013-04-12 and end_date is less than 2013-04-30. Which includes above record having 2013-04-16 as end_date

I tried with this query

`SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (start_date <='2013-04-12' AND end_date >='2013-04-30')` which dont give any result however if i put end_date 2013-04-15 it works fine

Comment: Why don`t use `BETWEEN` ?

Comment: how i can use that here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            '2013-04-12' as `start_date`,
            '2013-04-16' as `end_date`
    ) `sub`
WHERE
    (`start_date` BETWEEN '2013-04-12' AND '2013-04-30')
    AND
    (`end_date` BETWEEN '2013-04-12' AND '2013-04-30')
```

`BETWEEN` is more reliable

Comment: database table start date :2013-04-12 and end date : 2013-04-16 as per your above query wont work when end date is 2013-04-15

Comment: So why it should? You may change `AND` to `OR` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have start_date GREATER OR EQUAL 2013-04-12 and end_date LESSER OR EQUAL, than your operators are wrong:

```
start_date <='2013-04-12' AND end_date >='2013-04-30'
```

you should use >= for start_date and <= for end_date
like this:

```
start_date >='2013-04-12' AND end_date <='2013-04-30'
```

Comment: I tried this too, It works fine for date 2013-04-30 but when my end date is 2013-04-15 it wont give any result

Comment: It doesn't work when end date is earlier than start date?!? Well duh!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong operators ... start_date greater than(>=) end_date less than equal to (<=)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE (start_date >='2013-04-12' AND end_date <='2013-04-30')
```

Comment: I tried this too, It works fine for date 2013-04-30 but when my end date is 2013-04-15 it wont give any result

Comment: according to logic it should display everydate between 12 -30

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Convert(varchar,start_date,101) >'04/12/2013') AND convert(varchar,end_date,101) <'04/30/2013')
```

Comment: I tried this too, It works fine for date 2013-04-30 but when my end date is 2013-04-15 it wont give any result

Answer (score 0):

I would do:
    SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE start_date BETWEEN '2013-04-12' AND '2013-04-30'